# Solving a differential equation confusion

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do I solve this -

**$P'-7P+12y=0$ Where P is $dy/dx$.**
P.S-I tried to attempt using [clairauts Differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClairautsDifferentialEquation.html)
But it does not match that format.

Comment: With difficulty. The solution is a horrible expression involving the Lambert W function.

Comment: The answer is $y=c1e^{3x}+c2e^{4x}$

Comment: @JaiMahajan: For that answer, are you sure it isn't $12 y^2$? We would have $(p - 3y)(p-4y) = 0 \implies y' = 3y, y' = 4 y$.

Comment: Not sure,It might be a misprint in my book. Happened with another question in this chapter.

Comment: I think you are right,then the question's easy

Comment: @JaiMahajan: I agree, looks like a simple typo in the question.

Comment: Just to clarify $P^2 = \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}\right)^2$ and not $P^2 = \frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}$. Is $P$ and operator or a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ P= y^{'}= dy/dx $

Differentiating you get

$$ 2 y'y'' - 7 y'' + 12 y' =0 $$

$$y^{''} = \frac{12 y^{'}} {7-2 y^{'}} $$

$$\frac{dP}{dx} = \frac{12 P} {7-2 P} $$

you can take it from there.